# Extracting file from variable in a script file

Tags: bash

```
SRC=(*.c)



for j in $SRC
do
if test "'echo $j*.c'" != "$j*.c"; then
build.log/_compile -v $j*.c
fi
done
```

only extracts the first file  WHY? The idea was for the loop to extract and compile each file independantly giving multipule .o files.

Comment: You might want to look at using the [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob) shell option to better handle the case that `*.c` doesn't match anything

Comment: What is the purpose of `$j*.c`?  The variable `$j` will already have the `.c` extension.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that the echo command here shows only one file:

```
$ ls
file1.c  file2.c  file3.c  file4.c
$ src=(*.c)
$ echo $src
file1.c
```

If you want to access all the elements of an array, you must use a more complex form:

```
$ echo "${src[@]}"
file1.c file2.c file3.c file4.c
```

Thus, replace:

```
for j in $SRC
```

with:

```
for j in "${SRC[@]}"
```

The form `"${SRC[@]}"` is safe to use even if the file names contain whitespace or other difficult characters

#### Additional notes

1. It is best practices to use lower or mixed-case names for your shell variables.  The system uses upper case names for its variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.  Thus, it is good practice to use, for example, `Src` or `src` in place of `SRC`.
2. As steeldriver suggests, place this command at the beginning of your script:

   ```
   shopt -s nullglob
   ```

   With nullglob set, the `SRC` array will be empty if there are no `.c` files.